# Printing from Word to PDF in VB6

Tags: pdf, vb6, ms-word

I'm trying to print from Word to PDF, but selecting a different page range each time.

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Set objWord = New Word.Application
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "s:\reports\EY\FileName.doc", , , True
objWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut , , , "s:\test.pdf", , , , 1, "1-2"
```

My default printer is my PDF creator.

Document opens fine, the PDF is created, but it's unreadable.

Take the page range away, the PDF is correctly created, just the whole document.

I've search high and low for the `PrintOut` method parameters.

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237242%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237242%28v=office.12%29.aspx (just like jac said in his comment).

Anyway, here's a code that will print pages 3-5 of the current document to the default printer. Some of the values may be useless and may be removed, but this is what Word generates when I record a macro and print a document.

```
 objWord.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:=wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="3-5", PageType:=            wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False,            PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0,            PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

Please note the wdPrintRangeOfPages and wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, maybe this is what's missing.

(In the macro it was Application instead of objWord)

Comment: Thanks for the pages. They were the only ones I could find when I was searching.